# Unable to install and use python-docx?

Tags: python, django

I've been using django to build a web program that enables user input information within form tags to file i/o to a MS word(docx) document.
In order to do that, I've set up a virtualenv with django 1.7.6 and python-docx==0.8.5 installed. 
The problem is when I include "from docx import Document" in views.py, the HttpResponse 'index.html' returns an 'ImportError: No module name 'lxml''

As far as I understand, it should be a problem with lxml package, but I am unable to fix it. I've installed lxml according to lxml documentation, with command 'sudo apt-get install python3-lxml' but this doesn't work. Please help a helpless newbie. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running python 2.7.x or 3? if it's 2.7.6 you need python-lxml instead.

Comment: Activate your virtualenv and then install lxml using `pip install lxml`. Make sure the path of `pip` points to your virtualenv. To check the path, run the command `which pip`. I'm assuming you are not on Windows.

Comment: I'm running python 3.4.

Comment: @Bossam - Did my comment solve your problem? Why did you comment with my profile link? :P Click on `help` below the `Add Comment` button for info regarding tagging people. If that is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Bossam - Yup, you tagged me correctly this time. Since, you've been able to solve your problem, you should post the solution as your answer and give it a green tick. :) Happy Learning!

Comment: @JRodDynamite sorry, mate. I pretty new here. I guess I'm tagging you right this time.  You comment helped! Thanks. And apparently the reason it did not work was because I forgot to install the requirements of libxml2 & libxslt. Thanks.

Comment: @JRodDynamite How do you 'give a comment a green tick?' and post it as  the correct answer?

Comment: @Bossam - You can't green tick a comment. You can green tick an answer to indicate that the solution solved your problem. Below this page is a text editor to post your answer.

Comment: @JRodDynamite Thanks. Will do that. Apparently I can't accept my own answer within 2 days of posting.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @[JRodDynamite](https://stackoverflow.com/u/2932244)'s help, I was able to solve the problem.

You should:

1. Install all the requirements (`libxml2` & `libxslt`)
2. Then, install `lxml` with command `pip install lxml`.